# Problem with fill color

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, fill, polygon

I use the following command to create regular polygons. The 5th argument is there to insert options for styling the polygons. Though the line width is 0.3mm as I set it, it looks like the `fill=red` option is not accepted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,tkz-euclide,pgfplots,calculator}

\newcommand\polygon[5][]
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(#2-1)/2}
\FLOOR{\a}{\sol}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\startangle}{-90 + \angle/2}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,#2}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle + \angle*\i}
\draw[#5] (\x:#3) --  (\x + \angle:#3) -- cycle;
\tkzDefPoint(\x:#3){A_#2}
\tkzDrawPoint(A_#2)}
\foreach [count=\i] \j in {#4}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle - \angle*(\i+\sol)}
\node[anchor=center] at (\x:#3+.3) {$\j$};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.3mm] (0,0) circle (1);
\polygon[]{6}{1}{A,B,\varGamma,\varDelta,E,Z}{line width=0.3mm,fill=red}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't know if the structure of the command is not allowing any other option.

Comment: In `\draw[#5] (\x:#3) --  (\x + \angle:#3) -- cycle;` you have nothing to fill (this is just a segment drawn twice), so `fill=red` is useless here. It is not clear what you want to fill. Do you want `(0,0)` in place of `(cycle)` here?

Comment: I want to fill the area inside the polygon and I thought that it can be done trough `\draw` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am wondering why you don't follow approaches like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand\polygon[5][]{%
    \node[draw,#5,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#2,minimum size=2*#3cm] (p) {};
    \foreach \i[count=\j] in {#4} {
        \path (p.center)--(p.corner \j) node[pos=1.2] {$\i$};
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.3mm] (0,0) circle (1);
\polygon[]{6}{1}{A,B,\varGamma,\varDelta,E,Z}{line width=0.3mm,fill=red}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think you should not define a macro for this.

---

If you want to follow your way, [Kpym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9335/kpym) has given you the right way: use `(0,0)` instead of `cycle`. However, one has to do a bit more. Also, there will be a very thin white line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,tkz-euclide,pgfplots,calculator}

\newcommand\polygon[5][]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{(#2-1)/2}
    \FLOOR{\a}{\sol}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\startangle}{-90 + \angle/2}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#2} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle + \angle*\i}
        \fill[#5] (\x:#3) --  (\x + \angle:#3) -- (0,0);
        \draw[#5] (\x:#3) --  (\x + \angle:#3);
        \tkzDefPoint(\x:#3){A_#2}
        \tkzDrawPoint(A_#2)
    }
    \foreach [count=\i] \j in {#4} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle - \angle*(\i+\sol)}
        \node[anchor=center] at (\x:#3+.3) {$\j$};
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#2} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\startangle + \angle*\i}
        \tkzDefPoint(\x:#3){A_#2}
        \tkzDrawPoint(A_#2)
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=0.3mm] (0,0) circle (1);
\polygon[]{6}{1}{A,B,\varGamma,\varDelta,E,Z}{line width=0.3mm,fill=red}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first sulotion is neat and simple. I had no idea that there was a ready to use option for regular polygons. Also I realised, as Kpym mentioned, that each time I was drawing the same segment twice, so there was no polygon to fill.

Comment: My upvoted surely. Can you put, please, in first plane the gray bullet near `\Gamma`? There is a strange closure of the exagon.

Comment: @Sebastiano I will add in a while. However, I don't see anything strange.

Comment: @JouleV In the 2nd picture (2nd code).

Comment: Ah, ok, I will find some ways to solve. Anyway that way is not recommended clearly.